# Can I use two schema markup tag in my website for "location" and "product"

Tags: schema.org

I have already added schema markup for location in my website http://www.academiaerp.com/

But my website is a product so can I add Product Schema Tag also in my website?

Comment: Have you already tried to add a product schema tag? What's not working for you?

Comment: Please include a minimal (!) example of what you have, and another one for showing what you want to do (or a specific quesiton if don’t know how to do it).